# How to Change CLI or angular version using commands

Tags: angular, angular-cli

in my work bench currently installed version of CLI is angular 7. I wanted to change it to 5. Instead of changing package.json any other way to do it from the command prompt which update all the dependencies automatically?

Comment: It works with upgrades, I'm not sure it works with downgrades. You will have to do it by hand.

Comment: Why do you need to downgrade exactly ? That's usually not a bright idea ...

Comment: I reached in a scenario where I ran npm install and it gave me a lot of vulnerability then I ran npm audit. I found the project requires angular 5 as the test case is written for that. So of course I have to downgrade.

Comment: You don't have to downgrade your application, just wait for the vulnerabilities to be resolved. Otherwise, you will have to upgrade again.

Comment: My application expects angular 5 , and some how the package.json got changed as I executed lot of commands which I got after npm audit (oops my mistake) which I realized after few hours.

Comment: Don't you have a version manager ? Anyway, just use `npm prune; npm i` and everything shuld come back.

Comment: @trichetriche   When I run npm i I am getting below error

Comment: ** npm i
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...fPvhJpExLSAr0o9rlUeyV'**

Comment: @trichetriche version manager - are you talking about version control ( git , svn )

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade your global angular-cli installation by issuing:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8 // or whatever version you need
```

And then do the same in your project.

The `npm cache verify` is also a recommended option after `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: The question was more about how to edit all dependencies, such as `ng update`, but in reverse

Comment: @trichetriche yes I am looking for downgrade. Not like uninstalling and installing required version. But what I have seen is manually if you change CLI in package.json, then it gives an option to change the dependencies as well. So I believe there should be some command which does it.